# Grouping queries in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to get a query working to get grouped data out of a single schema. The schema looks like that

```
Message: {
sender: objectId,
recipient: objectId,
message: String
posted: Date
}
```

Each document is a plain message. A conversation would be a simple query of messages. Now I'd like to get the last X conversations with the last message.

```
Model.find({
'$or': [
  {
    sender: userId
  },
  {
    recipient: userId
  }
]
}, fields, {
    skip: (_page - 1) * PAGE_SIZE,
    limit: PAGE_SIZE
}, _cb);
```

How would I apply the grouping?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Would say aggregate fits the bill here. Run the following pipeline to get the last X conversation, bearing in mind the [`$skip + $limit` Sequence Optimization](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-optimization/#agg-sort-skip-limit-sequence):

```
var pipeline = [
    {
        "$match": {
            "$or": [
                { "sender": userId },
                { "recipient": userId }
            ]
        }
    },
    { "$sort": { "posted": -1 } },
    { "$limit": PAGE_SIZE },
    { "$skip": (_page - 1) * PAGE_SIZE }    
]
Model.aggregate(pipeline, _cb);
```

Comment: thanks, but this is not working. I assume I d need a $group property specifying what to aggregate